# no internet access in SharePoint Domain controller

Tags: 2016, azure

I have created a VM for sharepoint 2016 in Microsoft azure

I am not able to connect to the internet after I promoted the server as Domain Controller

Not able to figure out what IP I should use as forwarder

Comment: Set the DNS IP in azure Portal and restart your VM.

Comment: I hope that Missing Microsoft external DNS server was the root cause.  edit the Virtual Network, under the configure section - select external in the drop-down. An ip address 168.63.129.16 will automatically get set. Save the change and  restart